# Different Form Fields for Different Requirements

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a `Job Application Project`, `Admin Panel` and `Front End`.Add Vacancy from Admin panel and Apply from Front End Against a job using Application form. Requirements are.

> When Applying for a Specific job, Input Fields in the Application form can change for different Jobs. like some job can ask for Gender and some can ask for Age..?

Please Guide when Adding Vacancies, how can I Achieve point 1.. so different jobs have different Requirements...

Comment: Just think about it a little. What would you do when you see this question if you were answering? Its just so broad. I'm not sure what answer you expect.

Comment: so how do u want me to ask this question?

Comment: Start with what you have tried, break your problem into sub problems and tell us about them. Do you have a difficulty understanding the requirement? Do you have trouble changing controls on a form? **You** decide how you want to solve your problem, and we can provide technical advice to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into dynamically adding controls (textbox, checkbox, dropdown) at runtime according to what fields you need to display. This is fairly simple and there will be lots of example on SO and the internet in general.

Comment: Thanks for that.. i know it will b easy, and i had a good look about dynamic controls and now front end of the application form is clear,, but how would i go when i add Vacancies to my Database,,,based on my Database i would generate the form.. i am very new to .net so need some help.